# Are the two downvote tooltip reasons meant conjunctively or disjunctively?

Tags: discussion, voting

The downvote tooltip says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

This poses a particular problem for questions that are:

1. **Yes**: Obviously lacking research effort.
2. **No**: Not unclear, and even interesting (i.e. it *is* "useful" to know the answer).

These are often short, basic, interesting questions (e.g. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8417270/419956), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/419956)) that can be very helpful.

Would you downvote, upvote, or not vote for this type of question?

And how about the same question asked *again*? Obviously they should be marked for closing as a duplicate, but does such a question warrant a downvote if the duplicate is decently discoverable? If yes wouldn't that go against the "Vote based on content" adage?

PS. I've had this question for some time, never found an answer on the metas. Recent "[Why is SO so negative lately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/419956)" question triggered me to finally go and ask what the community thinks about this.

Comment: That's quite a good question. I'd interpret it as being useful and clear *because* of having research effort. If it was "research OR (clear AND useful)", then a serial comma should have been used instead (i.e. "This question is unclear, not useful or does not show any research effort." and vice versa). Of course, that's just the literal meaning, whether to do so on moral grounds is another matter.

Comment: Agreed, though I do think it's more interesting to find out what the community thinks the tooltip *should* be (as opposed to figuring out what the current tooltip implies, language-wise).

Comment: Given that [the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252747/419956) to another question answers mine as well, I'd guess my own question was a duplicate of that (more recent :S) question. Voted to close this one then.

Answer (score 2):

The first two questions you cited never received any downvotes.

The third question is a *general reference/canonical question*; its purpose is to provide a target for closing questions of the form "how do I fix this null reference exception" as duplicates.  This is made clear in the comments below the question.

It's a perfectly fine question, *the first time it is asked.*  It probably received downvotes exactly for the reason specified in the tooltip: "this question lacks research effort."

That's one of the pitfalls of such questions; people evaluate them based on the usual cookie-cutter template of Stack Overflow questions, which is "what have you tried?"  But if we're to be a repository for useful programming knowledge, these are the kinds of questions that we should be encouraging.  Highly-specific troubleshooting questions never help anyone else but the OP.