# When is it preferred to UP-vote a question?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

The recent discussion on [downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) grabbed my attention, as I'm very stringent about downvoting even a malformed question. That question gave me a lot of thought on this matter, but a similar question on upvoting might also need additional attention.

First, the tooltip for upvoting says "shows research effort, useful and clear". What kind of "AND" is this one? I see many questions on SO that don't show any research efforts, but are indeed clear and probably useful to other questioneers, as that question has an easily googlable title and/or body. I see that those questions that show research efforts, but are formulated as a decent heap of data, don't get any upvotes or only get a few, because of TL;DR effect that stops people from determining the question's worthiness or clarity. Sometimes question do need to have all the data included in them to nail the problem.

Second, is it appropriate to upvote a question in a "me-too" situation, even if that question is say a duplicate, possible duplicate, a malformed or otherwise unclear one, but you personally understand that the question is what you'd ask, and you need the answer on it?

Third, there are also "emotional" upvotes aka "likes" on questions that otherwise don't deserve an upvote, as they are only funny, but not showing research effort, clear or useful. Are these votes valid on SO?

Comment: The "downvote" version of your question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251980/are-the-two-downvote-tooltip-reasons-meant-conjunctively-or-disjunctively

Comment: I tend to favorite the questions I would have asked too, and upvote/downvote based on the regular merits of the question. If the question is poor quality, I have added incentive to edit it so that it is not flagged and gets more helpful answers.

Comment: There are lots of times that it's appropriate to upvote a duplicate.  Often duplicates arise because there's more than one way to describe a problem, or because it's hard to describe the problem until you know that it's "problem x".  The duplicates that help people who don't know the canonical name for it **are** helpful, and can still demonstrate research effort.  That's worth upvoting, because we **want** it to be a way to find the question that does have the answer.

Comment: I'd think that questions that fit the profile of your third point need to be flagged as 'Not an answer', you can upvote them as a comment all day long :)

Comment: @Styler Flagging questions as "Not an answer"? Sure, they are questions, not answers.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Personally, I tend to upvote a question when at least one of the following ring very true:

1. **It's obvious that OP tried something and/or did his homework** before asking. If he addresses the problem in such a way that he'd borrow as little work colleague time as possible at work, then he deserves some help and attention in my eyes. (Conversely, he'll get a downvote for not doing so.)
2. **It's written in such a way that it's *very* useful to future visitors**, as in well written and easy to run into using Google. Whether it is trivial or difficult matters little to me here, so long as it's not an obvious dup and the content is essentially guaranteed to help the next guy with the same problem.
3. **It's a genuinely difficult question** on a topic I've enough experience in to feel confident in judging the question's merit. By this, I mean that I'm either aware of the answer and know that someone less knowledgeable on the subject wouldn't know where to locate it, or unaware of the answer myself and would need to research it before providing one.

The third criteria is highly subjective, but it has a special place in my heart because I periodically head to the unanswered questions tab of my tag ghettos in the hopes of locating something interesting, and these are sorted by votes descending. Nothing makes me weep more than finding upvoted crap in there. (In particular, the mountains of "help me understand this error" posts where the OP is obviously not bothering to help himself by using whatever debugging tools are at his disposal.)

Comment: I do the same for the point 1 and 3: Well explained, "smart" searches made, interesting question (mind games, tricky thing, etc.).

Comment: I also upvote when I find the question useful to me.

Comment: I'm curious about the merit for #3.  As a novice myself, I often find "easy" questions to be extremely helpful.  It seems like the qualification for #3 is the OP being at the same or greater level of sophistication as the reader, and I don't see what makes that a desirable attribute for a question.

Comment: @naomisorbet: As I wrote, it's highly subjective. What may seem difficult to you might seem trivial to me and vice versa. I'd only upvote a question based on that criteria *if I feel proficient on the topic*. For those where I do not, my filter is primarily #2: it must be *very* useful for future visitors.

Comment: Why the distinction between *very* useful and just regular useful? And how would you quantify the difference? Personally, I would consider an upvote to be useful for future visitors and a bounty for something *very* useful for future visitors.

Comment: "*Nothing makes me weep more than finding upvoted crap in there.*" — This is very true in the `[php]` tag.

Comment: I'd like to point out that even the mighty @Denis has asked a few crap questions(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225510/how-to-make-use-of-a-makerc-file-when-running-sudo-make-vs-make) Don't know how `sh` variables work? its clearly spelled out in one of many man pages. You say in the question your `c is rusty` this question isn't even about `C`. The point is **EVERYONE** asks crap. Then they learn how not to ask crap.

Comment: @nsfyn55: I dunno about any mighty Denis, but we'll have to agree to disagree on your definition of crap. The difference between the question you highlighted and the crap being discussed here or in the related thread on why down vote is this: I actually opened my bag and explained what I had looked into and succeeded to do already. (And indeed: `man sudo` was not one of those things.)

Comment: @Denis I agree your question was the top most level of crap. A healthy log wrapped in gold tin foil if you will. In addition I would be willing to wager that this question was asked rather early in your involvement with SO. So if we go through all the comments and help you received and replaced it with flames for your apparent inability to read `man sudo`, closed your question outright, and then paraded it around meta as an example of yet another dolt spewing his crap question cannon at SO would you be as involved as you are?

Comment: @nsfyn55: After the edit on it? Sure, it didn't do it any good; noticed how an inept comment requesting more details can turn things around? Before that, sorry: we'll just need to disagree. Frankly though: I'd have loved someone to comment `man sudo` and close-vote the question. Except that I posted two bug reports on the homebrew and the relevant package on Github, both of which cross-referenced the question. You know what? I got a few a few users over there who didn't know any better than I or the other SO answerers here did. It took one of those two maintainers to post the correct answer.

Comment: (cont.) At any rate, it would fit my own #1 and #2 criteria. And probably #3 as well because, heck, how is anyone supposed to guess that `sudo` can import your entire environment with a simple switch when your working assumption is that it stands for "super-user do" and merely makes you run a command as root? In retrospect: sure, obvious. When you first run into the problem: it would be worth a mention in the Unix Hater's Handbook.

Comment: @Denis oh I see. While your question really isn't appropriate for SO because its a `general computing` question(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748045/sudo-e-option-does-not-work), its ok because it suits your subjective criteria. I bet every meta poster that rails on bad questions has a question in their attic like this one. A questions that they will gladly defend as "well its close but its ok for the following reasons".

Answer (score 5):

For me the **"AND" is a majority or threshold thing**. The more of the criteria are fulfilled, the better, although if one criteria is really badly unfulfilled it acts as a showstopper. Mathematically it would be something between addition and multiplication then. I guess this is reasonable because it balances the different goals.

For the **usefulness aspect of it, I try to take a non-personal view**. Is the question useful for others too? But of course I will visit questions that are useful for me much more often than others.

To summarize: If I think a question shows some research effort and is understandable and could be useful for a certain number of persons I will upvote it. There is no personal advantage or disadvantage attached to upvoting, so it's just more like a habit.

Answer (score 3):

Yet again, votes are only made to improve the quality of the content available on the website.

It should not be about you, it should not be personal, and it's just a way **for the community** to ensure that **the overall content quality** of the website remains high.

Do not get influenced by the votes already cast on a question. Maybe a question with 10 upvotes deserves a downvote. Maybe some perfectly formed and relevant question gets downvotes. An upvoter unable to search if a question has already been asked is just as bad as an asker unable to do some research.

Comment: If it shouldn't be "about you" or personal, what's an "emotional upvote"?

Comment: @Mat Good question. Let me put it this way: I expect quality questions to be upvoted so that I can see them. You should upvote questions, not because you like them, but because you think *the community* will find them interesting.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Not sure how you would rephrase that, you have the right to edit it. To keep it simple, I'll just get rid of the bullets and keep what most people seem to agree on, especially since Mat actually has a good point in his comment.

Comment: What I had in mind with the (former) second bullet was the april fool's questions. Every year we have a funny question, not really professional, yet crucial to the website because they keep the community friendly and welcoming. So I still upvote them every year for this very good reason, that's what I understood with "emotional upvote" (to keep this place a place people want to go to and contribute to), but it seems it's a wider term than that.

Comment: I cant possibly judge what the "community" will think of a post or not, i'm frequently admonished whenever I try.  I can only determine if it has value based on my experience and preferences.  Doing that, then extrapolating it to the large group of SO users is what gives us good or bad posts.

Answer (score -5):

Maybe upvote (or downvoting) need to be completed by a "level" of difficulty (from the asker) and a "why up/down vote" (from the voter).

A basic question without search and direct "do what I want" style is very different from a newcomer trying with some parameters that are not available together, but with a different level people could be totally lost even with a decent search (work constraint may deserve this search).

I often search google or SO for answers, but I don't find something, asking thus the question and someone just tag it as dummy or "duplicate" because it is a truly duplicate, but searches are not using the correct tools name (often unknown or on totally other idea).

I often upvote on questions not dummy (aka with effort from the asker) or tricky question (often special behaviour / side effect) from classical tools.

The reason of the up/down is useful for the asker to understand why there is something to promote or correct for future questions. It's very frustrating to have a downvote without reason when you make an effort on research and composition of request and not constructing for the community.

Comment: While your post is pretty unclear, the core point is understandable. Also, about "difficulty level" for questions, the assessor should have enough experience to properly set such a level, and recently people come up with ugly questions, sometimes even without any research or intent of it, so they plain cannot assess that level, so what will they set?

Comment: "level" is a bit off topic so i reply shortly. could be define by the community same way of up/downvote are done. It's just interesting to have it in voting system to estimate effort needed (relatively to level and knowledge) of asker (and maybe also for reply) and showing the effort already passed on it. A simple "i don't know how to handle it" could be enough to start the next step in effort.

Comment: sorry for the "unclear", nicety on non technical english is not easy for me

Comment: Up/down votes are simple. Difficulty level, why comment, no need to enforce any of that.

Answer (score -6):

I personally find that there are users who downvote posts unjustly, without making the slightest contribution to it, ie leaving a comment suggesting improvements.

If there are already other comments explaning what problems there are with the post, I do not mind downvoting.

In these cases I upvote the post just to show that the site is at least a bit welcoming. I do not agree with the notion that post quality is so much more important than the site being welcoming to new users, so:

**Yes, I upvote posts which are downvoted without explanation, even if I otherwise wouldn't vote them up.**

I hope that I make a small contribution to deter users from downvoting without making suggestions for improvements. Downvotes are not supposed to be taken personally, but they *are* taken personally (especially by new users), and that is something we should, I think, recognize.

(I think downvoting without commenting should be penalized in reputation, but that's another matter.)

Comment: My justification for downvoting you was due to the weather.  It's overcast here and it's putting me in a mood.

Comment: (For better reading:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1079354)

Comment: Thanks, good link. Alright, if you think the weather is gonna be better by downvoting this post, you are welcome to downvote it :) I do think my practice makes SO more welcoming, that's my reason to follow it.

Comment: The canonical is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)*.

Comment: Upvoting bad questions tells people that their bad questions are ok. That's unwelcoming to everyone else who doesn't want to deal with so many bad questions.

Comment: When I look for a question, I usually find the ones which are worded in a way which makes them easy to find. Those are usually highly upvoted, and most of the time helpful. I don't usually bother looking at ones which have score around 0. I think most users share this view. I don't think that bringing a question back from -1 to 0 is a distraction (not even from -2 to -1: I don't think anyone trying to find answers will consider posts with -1 score). I make exceptions with my upvoting habit if post has very bad style (I sometimes even downvote in those cases).